# JQuery Content slider: 3 x content sliders, none of which QUITE work. Samples provided

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, carousel

I have to build a content gallery for a client that has the following specifications:

1. There will be two galleries on the page.
2. They will be within lightboxes- users will click links, and the galleries will open in modal windows.
3. The galleries will have next/prev buttons that will sit on top of the sliding content
4. The galleries will contain both images and text/other content within each slide.

I have 3 examples of galleries I've built that don't quite do what they're supposed to, each in their own unique way:

1: **Gallery Attempt One**, based on the fearlessflyer slider: [DEMO HERE](http://www.steph-morris.com/slidertest/index_rollmyown.html#)

*What doesn't work on this one*: Buttons sit inside of each list item. I attempted to fix this by putting absolutely positioned images as fake buttons on top of the actual links, but this created an impossible-to-solve Z-Index issue in Internet Explorer. Damn.

My JQuery chops were not up to writing a new function so that the buttons could be independent of the LIs and trigger the sliding by counting how many times a button had been clicked, so I tried another solution:

2.**Gallery Attempt Two**, Based on TinyCarousel: [DEMO HERE](http://www.steph-morris.com/slidertest/index_tinycarousel.html)

*What works about this one:* Everything! It's great! I like the automatic enabling/disabling of that "Prev" button. No limit to how many carousels. Awesome. Except...

*What doesn't work:* For some reason I can't understand, putting the TinyCarousels inside of modal windows de-activates the buttons. The buttons literally acquire a class of "disabled" and stop working. Why? NO IDEA. Tried to fix it by using removeClass to take off the "disable" class. Didn't fix it. Out of ideas.

1. **Gallery Attempt Three**, Based on excellent [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZqXs/) by Stackoverflow user Kei. [DEMO HERE](http://www.steph-morris.com/slidertest/index_clicker.html)

*What doesn't work*: This one plays nice with two galleries on the page, works inside of a modal window, but... the entire JQuery is targeting the IMG specifically, not the LI, so it won't work for my additional text content.

So, can anyone provide a solution or suggestion for either:

1. Adding static buttons to Gallery Attempt One
2. Fixing the bug in TinyCarousel that disables the galleries inside of modal windows
3. Modifying Gallery Attempt Three so that it targets all content within an LI, not just the IMG, or
4. A lightbox+gallery solution that you know does all of these things straight out of the box and allows for easy CSS customisation?

**Further gallery attempts:**

1. BXgallery: doesn't work because it dynamically detects the size of it's content and sizes itself accordingly, making it 0px high & wide when the content is initially hidden in a modal window. [DEMO HERE](http://www.steph-morris.com/slidertest/index_bxslider.html)

Comment: What a coincidence, I was going to publish a jQuery plugin I wrote over the last couple of weeks, it's a slider but you'll have to do most of the stuff on your own (buttons for example). I'll post the link here as soon as I'm done writing some doc (in the next few hours I guess).

Comment: I look forward to seeing your slider!

Comment: I see you solved your problem, congrats, but here's my slider anyway if you ever need it: http://pioul.fr/jquery-diyslider/

Comment: Hey, it looks great, well done! One thing I noticed while using the demo on the page is that the "back" and "forth" buttons take you all the way to the end and all the way to the beginning, rather than paging through the slides. Is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: Thank you! It's the intended behavior when the option "loop" is set to true (and it is by default).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I gave in and used AnythingSlider.

I wanted to stay away from it because it's so full-featured that it can be a customisation headache, and I remembered the default CSS being quite dense to wade through and style properly.

But since I was obviously losing a LOT more time trying sliders that didn't work than I would have spent just untangling the default CSS of AnythingSlider, I gave in and tried it. Had it decently styled in under an hour.

Ta-da, it works: [DEMO HERE](http://steph-morris.com/slidertest/index_anythingslider.html)

1. It works with two galleries on the page
2. It works inside of modal windows
3. The controls sit on top of the gallery
4. It works with text & image content.

Moral of the story: sometimes the obvious answer is obvious for a reason.